# add image to magento admin menu title tag?

Tags: image, admin-panel, adminmenu

How to show image beside admin menu item?
 below is the code where i need to add image inside `<title>`

`

```
<config>
    <menu>
    <custommodule module="module" translate="title">
    <title> <img src="src"/> custom menu</title>
    </custommodule>
    </menu>
    </config>
```

Answer (score 1):

Magento does not allow images in the admin menu by default.
You need to rewrite the method `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu::_buildMenuArray` and either allow an image tag, or add a class to each menu item depending on the module name or menu url and do your magic via css.

Comment: how can i allow images...?